# Variable expression %Var% not working in for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, variable-expansion

```bat
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (java -jar %MAVEN_HOME%\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://someip.com build /dev/ -s  --username **** --password ***) DO (SET var=%F)
```

Here `%MAVEN_HOME%` value is not getting replaced with the actual value but when I run this without the `for` loop it is working fine.

Can some please get this resolved and get the `MAVEN_HOME` replaced with actual value?

Comment: If this is in a .bat file script, you must double the `%` character on the `F` variable. Use `%%F`. Also, put the java command in apostrophes. If you want to put the command in backticks (GRAVE ACCENT), then you must specify `"usebackq tokens=*"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the command in `` ` ` `` like this

```bat
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`java -jar %MAVEN_HOME%\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://someip.com build /dev/ -s  --username **** --password ***`) DO (SET var=%F)
```

because the syntax is

```bat
C:\>for /?
Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.

FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.

...

FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]

    or, if usebackq option present:

FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('string') DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]
```

As you can see, you have `USEBACKQ` so the command must be surrounded by backticks, and it also said that you have to double the percent if you want to use the `for` command in a batch file

Comment: Hey @phuclv, This way also not helping me. The problem is after using quotes this command is misbehaving..even it is removing few words from command.Please try executing this command

Comment: @arjun, if you're running the command from a batch file, _which you should be because you've added a tag for it_, you need to also double up the percent characters for the metavariable, `%F` becomes `%%F`!

Comment: @arjunkumarmehta if you run `for /?` you'll see that "To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify `%%variable` instead of `%variable`"

Comment: Hey, Thanks all, finally it works. including ' ' is the right answer.